# NavigationBarColor does not apply when keyboard is visible

Tags: android, android-navigation-bar

I set custom color to my navigation bar using **navigationBarColor**. However I see black navigation bar when keyboard poups on top of my activity. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/AppThemeDialogue</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    </style>
```

[image: This is how my navigation bar looks inside an activity]

This is how my navigation bar looks inside an activity

[image: This is how navigation bar looks when keyboard pops up]

This is how navigation bar looks when keyboard pops up

Comment: Add your xml and code to change the color.

Comment: @TheAnkush I am not clear on what you said

Comment: Add the source code of file. The code you are using to set navigationBarColor.

Comment: @TheAnkush I have added my app theme snippet

Comment: Add a screenshot for clarification

Comment: @GiddyNaya I have added the screenshots

Comment: I have the same issue with Swift Keyboard. I'm guessing that it is because the keyboard is an app in its own right, and that it's theme overrides the app theme. It is not terribly helpful though as it looks dreadful

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try this one -

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR);
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
```